# why "knife zero converge " request password

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I've set -x root ,why zhengdong@192.168.10.181,and requst password,
I also tried knife zero bootstrap 192.168.10.181 -x root -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa --sudo
it doesn't work

**Screenshot shared below:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your SSH key(s) are not accepted it will fall back to a password automatically.